# JQuery Mobile data-transition="slide" in asp.net not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I have a asp.net website running on DNN 7.1 which is written in c#. I have existing ascx control in a module with a asp:Button. on button click, server side I do a Response.Redirect. I am creating new skin using JQuery Mobile to run it on mobile phones and on button click the URL is not changing but the browser is loaded with redirected page. So, when I use back button on the browser, it looks like URL changes, but it is exactly the same and previous page is not being loaded. From other posts on this site I found I need to disable ajax call using following code.

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    $.extend($.mobile, {
        linkBindingEnabled: false,
        ajaxEnabled: false
    });
});
```

But now the data-transition sliding effect is not happening. I read on JQuery Mobile site if ajax is disabled data-transition has no effect (correct me if I am wrong). So, How can I have both asp:Button (which generates input element with type submit) click change the browser URLs and have data-transition? I am new to JQuery Mobile, so, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: add `data-ajax="false"` to `form` which disabling ajax globally `ajaxEnabled: false`.

Comment: @Omar: Do I need to add data-ajax="false" on the form tag but remove ajaxEnabled: false from mobileinit? Sorry could you please elaborate on what you said.

Comment: Yes, this way you don't disable ajax globally, you just disable it on request on specific items. Sorry my previous comment was vague. Remove ajaxEnabled=false.